# How to do a center alignment for the combo box data in powerapps

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas

I have a powerapp combobox in a view mode in the view screen. How to do a center alignment of the object which is placing at the top of the combobox.

I have tried the below code in the Left padding but I see no change in the alignment.
`(Self.Width-30-Len(Self.Selected.DisplayName)*10)/2`

Any suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

[image]